# Android: Is a while loop efficient?

Tags: android, performance, drawing

Currently I'm using the following construction:

```
while(continue)
{
    if(somethingChanged)
    {
        draw();
    }
}
```

Is this way of waiting efficient, or is there a better way to do this?

--

As requested, more info:

I'm drawing on a SurfaceView, with a Thread locking the Canvas and calling the onDraw(Canvas) method. When the thing I have drawn hasn't changed, I don't need to call the onDraw(Canvas) method, so I keep a boolean somethingChanged.

Also, when I touch the screen, I draw let's say a circle at the point of touch, so when I'm touching the screen, somethingChanged is true.

Comment: Inadequate information found. Unable to answer.

Comment: What is the something you are waiting to change? What are you drawing into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use a `wait()` and make the other threads `notify()` this one when something has changed (if the somethingChanged is changed by other threads).

Comment: But is that a 'better' way than running a loop, in ways of efficiency?

Comment: Yes, of course, during the `wait()` your thread will be paused and will use 0% CPU instead of 100% (if you use an infinite loop). And the display will be updated exactly when you need. With a `sleep()` you will still use very few CPU but the drawing will not be exactly in real time.

Answer (score 2):

You probably doing a game, I recommend that article: http://dewitters.koonsolo.com/gameloop.html There are very good possible solutions for your request.

Comment: Indeed, it’s a very good read. But if your game does not need to redraw itself when the users is idle, you will probably not find the answer to your question (the article is only considering games where you want to have the highest FPS)

Answer (score 2):

Android has a better mechanism regarding idle loops than the std java approach.
It consists of a Looper and a Handler which do the work for you:

```
Handler myHandler;
...
public void run() { 

       Looper.prepare(); //this tells Android that your thread will contain a loop

       myHandler = new Handler() {

              public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                      draw();  
              }
       };
Looper.loop; //starts the loop
}
```

All you have to do to call the draw method is to send a message to that handler instead of setting the boolean var.

```
Message mess;
myHandler.sendMessage(mess)
```

That way you can also send any object in that message to the loop, too and android does the thread synchro and message queue stuff for you. And - most importantly - it is efficient, too.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing changed, this is an endless loop that will very probably use 100% cpu, so I'd say that you should at least add some `Thread.sleep()` calls to give other threads a chance do to something (e.g. changing the value of `somethingChanged`)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, in infinite loops, you should have some mechanism to avoid it to take over all time of the cpu. This is done, for example, with a sleep. Even a brief sleep will alleviate the use of the processor.
 Assuming that this code is in an thread:

```
while(continue)
{
    if(somethingChanged)
    {
        draw();
    }
    Thread.sleep( mySleepTime );
}
```

Comment: So then a sleep of only 30ms would be enough? (To keep my circle moving smoothly)